# Can't select column that exists on a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm adding 3 new columns to a table in SQL but I can't select them after adding, it just says that the columns are invalid

I added them through this command

```
alter table tb_example add x varchar(50) null
alter table tb_example add y varchar(50) null
alter table tb_example add z varchar(50) null
```

If I `select * from tb_example` everything appears there, but the columns are not functional, I can't insert any data or select said columns

I have no idea why this is happening, nothing similar ever happened before, anyone has any ideas on what is causing this issue?

The issue appears when I try something like `select x from tb_example`

x gets underlined in red and I get the error "invalid column name 'x'." when I hover my cursor ever it, but when I run a `select * from tb_example` x, y and z are there

This only happens when I select x, y or z, the other columns work fine

Comment: Please show us the actual query which isn't working.

Comment: What tool are you using for querying, sql server management studio?  Could it be you have to refresh the data model in the tool?  What is the exact errors you are getting when A) you do `select top(10) x from tb_example` or `insert into tb_example (x) values ('Hi')`?  Also could you have column level security setup?  Hard to imagine you would have security to add columns but not select them...  [link](https://blog.netwrix.com/2019/06/27/how-to-implement-row-and-column-level-security-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Please check that your columns are not with quotations like "x", "y" or "z". Try to select something like : select "x" from tb_example. Also add the error.

Comment: Hovering your cursor is one thing, just means the auto-correct cache hasn't updated (because it doesn't know you've run an alter statement), but does it actually give an error when you run it (F5)? My guess is that it will just run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after updating, I'm having another unrelated issue and jsut wanted to rule this out